# Stuck on grub rescue "no such device", "unknown filesystem"

Tags: debian, windows, grub

i have a laptop with Windows installed on my eMMC chip and Debian 12 on a USB. I'm trying to boot Windows without having to select the Windows bootloader from the grub menu which to access, i need to boot from the USB where debian is installed. What im trying to achieve is to boot windows without having this USB stick, but if i unplug it I'll get this:

```
error: no such device: *My USB's UUID*
error:unknown filesystem
Entering rescue mode...
```

I tried a lot of things like changing boot order, fixmbr, reinstalling debian, nothing works and since im using it with me on the go I'd really like not having to carry a usb stick around just to select windows bootloader...

Comment: Is your system using UEFI firmware or a legacy BIOS? In other words, does `/sys/firmware/efi/` exist in Linux?  It seems like some part of your GRUB does exist on the eMMC, but it needs the contents of your Linux `/boot/grub` directory to fully work... and when the USB stick is not present, the inability to load further GRUB modules makes GRUB unable to boot Windows.

Comment: Read this [chainloader](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/453124/add-windows-10-to-grub2-bootloader#453302) It will explain a lot.

Comment: Read this [chainloader](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/453124/add-windows-10-to-grub2-bootloader#453302) This will tell you exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I ended up fully reinstalling Windows recently which re-wrote the boot loader and put Windows BootManager up first, i can now boot Windows without having to use supergrub2 on a USB stick. I can still boot on Debian like normal if i wish to

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when I tried to install Zorin OS on another USB drive.

- Booted to Zorin OS from live USB and opened the Boot Repair tool.
- In the 'Others' tab there was an option to repair Windows boot loader.

It fixed the problem in a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like GRUB (or at least some parts of it) have been installed on the eMMC: otherwise you could not possibly get into GRUB rescue mode with the USB stick unplugged.

If you have a UEFI system, you should be able to go into firmware settings (also known as "BIOS settings" although UEFI is not BIOS), check your laptop's documentation. Usually there is an on-screen prompt suggesting the key to press, but you might have to be very quick: once you know the right key to press, just start repeatedly pressing the key as soon as you power up the system ("spam the key").

Once you get into firmware settings, find the boot order settings there. To boot into Windows, set "Windows Boot Manager" as the first boot priority, instead of "debian". UEFI allows operating systems and bootloaders to have custom human-readable names, unlike classic BIOS.

Comment: I did try changing the boot order multiple times but grub always goes first no matter what... Since this is an old post i just accepted my faith and carry the USB stick around :(

Comment: In that case, you may have a UEFI firmware bug. A firmware update ("BIOS update") might help, if your laptop vendor has one available. Sadly, when UEFI was introduced, there were initially a lot of bugs in the early UEFI implementations, and even now, some manufacturers might only test for compatibility with Windows and once it is achieved, that's good enough for them.